# Не прорисовывается окно. Два окна при тройном переходе перестают прорисовываться. Консоль ошибок не пишет

Tags: java, javafx

Пробую сделать записную книжку. Два окна: первое - главное, второе - для написания заметки.

Переходы между окнами: с первого на второе - норм, со второго на первое - норм, с первого на второе - не прорисовывается, то есть кнопки есть, но их не видно и нажимаются вслепую. При нажатии осуществляется дальнейшие переходы, но все остальные окна не прорисовываются. 
Если изменить размер окна потянув за край, то элементы появляются.
Консоль ошибок не пишет.

В инете пока не нашёл ответа на свой вопрос. Возможно как-то неправильно формулирую запросы.

```java
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}



package sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    @FXML
    private Button buttNewNote;


    @FXML
    void initialize() {

        buttNewNote.setOnAction(event -> {

            openNewScene("/sample/note.fxml", buttNewNote);

        });
    }


    // Принимает адрес нового окна и нажатый элемент.
    public void openNewScene(String window, Button elem){

            // (вариант-1)
        //elem.getScene().getWindow().hide(); 
            // (вариант-2)
        Stage stageOld = (Stage) elem.getScene().getWindow();
        stageOld.close();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            // (вариант-1)
        //loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/views/signUp.fxml"));
            // (вариант-2)
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(window));

        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Присваиваем полный путь к файлу, который необходимо загрузить.
        Parent root = loader.getRoot();

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        // окно для загрузки. В качестве параметра передаём класс Scene с параметром пути для подключения root.
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        // ожидание прорисовки окна.
        stage.showAndWait();
    }
}




package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class noteController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textFieldNote;

    @FXML
    private Button buttSaveNote;


    Controller controller = new Controller();

    @FXML
    void initialize(){

        buttSaveNote.setOnAction(event -> {

            controller.openNewScene("/sample/sample.fxml", buttSaveNote);

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: почему используется `showAndWait()`?

Comment: `showAndWait` - это не ожидание прорисовки окна, это показать окно и ждать его закрытия. Работа вызывающего окна по сути блокируется.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь существует нюанс с тем, в каких случаях использовать метод `show()` и `showAndWait()`.

В двух словах, есть главные(родительские) окна, из которых вы открываете дочерние.

Так вот дочерние окна, это те, которые вы открываете на время, делаете какие то операции и возвращаетесь к главным.

По этому при открытии дочернего чаще всего, выгодно использовать `showAndWait()`, например при вводе новых данных, как бы приостанавливая главный процесс, дабы соблюдалась последовательность.

Но при закрытии дочернего и возврате к главному(при закрытии которого закрывается программа) желательно использовать метод `show()`, дабы не остановить важных процессов, из за чего могут виснуть дочерние окна.